# Python File is not running when put in a batch script

Tags: python, postgresql, batch-file

I have a python script that connect PostgresSQL.

Below is the script.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect('connection string')
try:
  curr = conn.cursor()
  sql_strng = "SELECT * FROM tbl"
  ### Further operations###
except(Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
      print("error",error)
finally:
    if (conn):
       conn.close()
```

The above code works well when I run it from Spyder. But when I try to run this from command prompt using a batch script it gives error as shown below.
My batch script:

```
C:\Users\Anaconda3\python.exe \path\to\python\file
```

The above batch script is throwing error as follows.

```
if(conn):
NameError: name 'conn' is not defined
```

Where I am missing out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the connection string global. Also put an exception handler for the connection string as below:

```
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(connection string)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This will tell you if your connection has gone through or not

Comment: What exactly you mean by "connection string global". Did you mean we should not use any `finally` block?

Comment: @pythondumb If you make the connection string variables as Global, it means variable values are not over written when using the same variable name. Ex: def conn_string():
    global myGlobal
    username = abcd

Also, if you need to close the connection directly put the conn.close() instead of placing it in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

If `psycopg2.connect` throws an exception, the `conn = ...` assignment is never executed, which means that when you arrive at `if (conn)`, `conn` is still undefined.